# About a closed strucure on profunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $Prof$ the bicategory with   profunctors (on small categories), arrows are like $D: \mathscr{A} \dashrightarrow \mathscr{B}$ and this means that $D: \mathscr{A}^{op} \times  \mathscr{B}\to Set$.

Its well known that there are (faithful and locally full and faithful) immersions $(-)_\bullet: Cat \to Prof ,\ (-)^\bullet: Cat^{op} \to Prof $ (where $Cat$ is the usual 2-category, and $Cat^{op}$ dualizes (reverses) arrows only).

We can extend the (cartesian) monoidal products:

defining for $ \mathscr{A} \dashrightarrow B$ and $E: \mathscr{C} \dashrightarrow \mathscr{D}$ the profunctor $D  \times   E: \mathscr{A} \times   \mathscr{C} \dashrightarrow \mathscr{B} \times   \mathscr{D}$ as the composition
$(\mathscr{A} \times   \mathscr{C})^{op} \times  (\mathscr{B} \times   \mathscr{D}) \cong
(\mathscr{A} \times   \mathscr{B}^{op} )\times  (\mathscr{C} \times   \mathscr{D}^{op})
\xrightarrow{D\times E } Set \times  Set \xrightarrow{\times  } Set$

If I'm not wrong  the immersions $(-)_\bullet,\ (-)^\bullet$ come out strict monoidal.

***I ask if $Prof$ has also a (monoidal) closed structure (I tried in vain to get it..)***

**Edit**: changed $\otimes$ in $\times$ (At first I thought the problem into enriched context).

Comment: To clearify: Objects in Prof are profunctors? What are the morphisms you consider? There are several possibilities.

Furthermore: I suggest you use another notation for the product of profunctors as '$\otimes$' is usually used for the composition of profunctors. I'd suggest '$\boxtimes$'. It is usually used for 'outer prodcts' like the one describe.

Comment: Also: What is the functor $\otimes:Set\times Set \to Set$? The cartesian product? What is the functor $\otimes:Cat\times Cat\to Cat$ you use?

Comment: objects are small categories, profunctors are arrow, the symbol $\otimes$ is the cartesian prodoct of categories (monoidal product in the cartesian monoidal structure).

Answer (score 6):

If by monoidal closed structure you mean the appropriate 2-dimensional analogue of the familiar 1-dimensional concept, then unless I misunderstand your question, the answer is that the bicategory $Prof$ is in fact compact closed: the dual of a small category $A$ in the sense of compact closure is the ordinary dual $A^{op}$, meaning that there is a 2-natural equivalence $Prof(A \times B, C) \simeq Prof(B, A^{op} \times C)$. This is essentially obvious since both sides are equivalent to the category of functors $A^{op} \times B^{op} \times C \to Set$ in a 2-natural way.

This generalizes the familiar fact that the bicategory $Rel$ (of sets, relations, and inclusions between relations) is compact closed, where the dual of a set = discrete small category $A$ is itself. More examples and discussion of this type can be found in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1053v3.pdf) by Mike Stay.